# Google Auth does not allow account selection after signing out

Tags: google-api, google-api-client

I use the following to let Google users authenticate my app to access their calendars and basic profiles:

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn({scope: 'profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'});
```

The AuthInstance in question is initiated like this at bootstrap:

```
var googleAuth = gapi.auth2.init({
    'client_id': 'XXX',
    'immediate': false,
    'cookie_policy': 'single_host_origin',
    'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
});
```

The above works just fine - the user gets a windows prompting her to select and login to one of her Google accounts, and after doing so authenticated requests can be made.

However, if the user signs out, using the following:

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
```

and then tries to sign in again, the window will just open, close, and sign her in automatically with the same account she signed in with earlier. This persists even if the page is refreshed, and the only solution is to clear cookies.

How can I make sure that signing a user out allows her to again select which account to sign in with next time she does so?

Comment: So, is you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that to make this work you need to revoke the access token entirely, using:

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().disconnect()
```